# How to get the Id of of setData in firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm writing a flutter app in which I set an instance of a document in firebase like this:

```
await _firestoreInstance.collection("groups").document().setData(
{
  'group_name': groupName,
  'class_name': className,
  'location': groupLocation,
  'time': groupTime,
  'date': groupDate,
  'number_in_group': 1
},);
```

Then I want to take the above document id and do something like this:

```
  _firestoreInstance.collection("colleges").document(collegeStudent.collegeId).collection('activeGroups').document().setData({'group_id':*above document id goes here*}); //above document id is the id of the document created by the first query
```

So my question is there a way I can get the id of the first document and use it as a reference for the second query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simplify `document().setData(data)` I used [`add(data)`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/collection_reference.dart#L57) in my solution, which does exactly the same and returns the `DocumentReference` from `document()`.

```
// insert your data ({ 'group_name'...) instead of `data` here
final DocumentReference documentReference = 
  await _firestoreInstance.collection("groups").add(data);

final String groupID = documentReference.documentID;

// groupID contains the documentID you were asking for
// here I am just inserting it into your example code from the question
_firestoreInstance.collection("colleges").document(collegeStudent.collegeId)
  .collection('activeGroups')
  .add({'group_id': groupID}); // using add instead of `document().setData` here as well
```

As you can see I am making use of the returned `DocumentReference` (as explained above) and using the [`documentID` getter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart#L34) to extract the ID from your newly created document.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code to execute `setData` and get the ID from `groups`.

```
var groups = _firestoreInstance.collection("groups");

await groups.document().setData(
{
    'group_name': groupName,
    'class_name': className,
    'location': groupLocation,
    'time': groupTime,
    'date': groupDate,
    'number_in_group': 1
});

groups.documentID
```